# RequireJS non-AMD files

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I'm attempting to use LeafletJS with requireJS and some LeafletJS plugins. I know that if you are using files that aren't AMD modules, you need to shim them in the config. Does this mean I will have to shim each individual plugin with the LeafletJS dependency? Ex:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'leaflet':         'vendor/leaflet/leafletjs',
        'leafletplugin1':         'vendor/leaflet/leafletplugin1',
        'leafletplugin2':         'vendor/leaflet/leafletplugin2'
    },
    shim: {
        'leafletplugin1': {
            deps: 'leaflet'
        },
        'leafletplugin2': {
            deps: 'leaflet'
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is that I plan to have many libraries with many plugins, and this config will get extremely long since I have to not only shim each individual plugin but also provide a path for each. Is there a simpler way to do this? It would be nice if I could even define a require.config inside of a module for use only with that module, that way I could keep my project better organized and less cluttered.

Also, there is no other way to simply `require(['leafletplugin1'], function(){});` without shimming it, correct?

EDIT: Just to clarify, this doesn't have to be a LeafletJS-specific question/answer. This is just the current example I'm working with.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**: depending on your build process and..

- Number of plugs
- Total size of plugins

would be concat all of the 'leaf' plugins into a single file.

**Option 2**: Turn all the plugins into proper modules.

This would mean having a `~/leaf` directory and a `~/leafModule` directory and having the build process "wrap" each plugin into a proper module.

In a similar situation, I did option 2.  Was fairly easy and made the rest of my code far easier to work on.

Comment: Having the build process wrap them into a module, is this something requireJS will do for you or some something to add to my grunt workflow myself? And I'm assuming you mean to just manually wrap the code in a define() to return the Leaflet object?